# How to add a point to an OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, markers

I have this:

```
let draw;
let save;
let dibujo;
let coordinates = [];
let old_coordinates = [];
let map;
const source = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
});
const style = {
    'icon': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 1],
        src: 'imgs/marker.png',
      }),
    }),
};
const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
    }),
    style: function (feature) {
    return style[feature.get('type')];
    },
});

function init() {
const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        keyboardEventTarget: document,
        target: "mapa",
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: "EPSG:4326",
            center: [-1.790436, 43.356794],
            zoom: 16,
            extent: [-9.844, 35.747, 4.878, 43.993],
        }),
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    testHome()
    map.on("click", function (evt) {
        if(dibujo == true){
            point = new ol.geom.Point(evt.coordinate)
            const marker = new ol.Feature({
                type: 'icon',
                geometry: point,
            });
            coordinates.push(marker)
            old_coordinates = []
            vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(marker)
        }
    });
}

function testHome(){
    point = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.790878,43.357910]))
    const home = new ol.Feature({
        type: 'icon',
        geometry: point,
        name: "Home"
    });
    vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(home)
    source.changed();
}
```

It should show a home point on the given lon,lat coordinates but it doesn´t work, any ideas?
The thing is, the code on the click event does work, why doesn´t testHome?

Comment: If your view projection is EPSG:4326 you do not need to convert LonLat coordinates using `ol.proj.fromLonLat`